# Can I add a break tag into a span that is created by Divi?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, divi

I'm trying to use Divi's pricing modules, but want the "subtitle" field to be broken into two lines. Normally, I can just add a break tag to the Divi field, and it reads it normally and breaks the line, but for some reason, it's spitting out this html:

```
<span class="et_pb_best_value">50% of 1st Month's Rent&lt;br /&gt;7.5% of Monthly Rent*</span>
```

I thought maybe I could use jQuery to add a break tag, but I'm not super familiar with jQuery.

Here's what I tried most recently, and it doesn't seem to do anything at all on the website:

```js
jQuery('.et_pb_best_value').html(function(_, curr){
    return curr.replace(',', '<br />');
});
```

```html
<span class="et_pb_best_value">50% of 1st Month's Rent,7.5% of Monthly Rent*</span>
```

Comment: Did you include jQuery in the page via a `<script>` tag? If so, was it before or after your script?

Comment: @phuzi Yes, the jQuery library is enqueued in the functions.php file and works on every page

Comment: If you include jQuery in the snippet above then it appears to work!

Comment: Show us the code you are using to create the first span.

Comment: @phuzi The code is generated by Divi. I just type in "50% of 1st Month's Rent,7.5% of Monthly Rent*" and the html I see in the inspect tool is <span class="et_pb_best_value">50% of 1st Month's Rent,7.5% of Monthly Rent*</span>

Here's the URL if it helps: http://piersidepmstag.wpengine.com/pricing/